# Import only works in interpreter

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key',
                  consumer_secret= 'consumer_secret',
                  access_token_key='access_token_key',
                  access_token_secret='access_token_secret')
```

Above code works fine in the interpreter and I am able to get the information that I am looking for. However, `python importScript.py` with the exact contents above gives error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Api'
```

I am not sure what the issue is and have searched for related issues with no resolution. My python interpreter and command are the same version.

Comment: What' s your project structure?

Comment: Is the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable set? If so, what are the contents of the file it points to?

Comment: The error does not fit the given code. This error would be raised if you have an import of the form `from twitter.Api import ...` or `from Api import ...`. Please add the full error traceback.

Comment: My guess: you have a python file or package in your project called `twitter`. You have to rename it.

Comment: I checked the project structure of twitter. api.py (please note its not Api) is the module name which has different classes like Twitter and so on. Try this `from twitter.api import Twitter`

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you! What a trivial thing, you saved me. Please enter your comment as an answer and I will give you a check.